# How to Transition Scenes with Collision Detection in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm currently working on a project for my game design, and I'm having trouble figuring out a problem. My two local sources (The School Wiki and the Help Desk) didn't help me, so I was recommended to this site.

So, say I have a hero (instance name is "player"), and he's running around, but in order to transition to the next scene, he has to run into a block (instance name is "transitionblock").

Thank You,
BaconPotato

Comment: Use an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener, and check for collision inside, if there's one, do transition. Should be as simple as that. Don't forget to remove the listener once the transition is initiated.

Answer (score 0):

Vesper's comment gives a sufficent explanation, but when using this code for the first time, its helpful to have a reference. This is how I would do it:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onFrame)

public function onFrame(e:Event) {
    if (player.hitTestObject(transitionBlock)) {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onFrame)
        //we remove the event listener to increase performance speed
        gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2")
        //this line will only work if you want to go to a scene called "Scene 2"
    }
}
```

I haven't run this code, so reply or edit if it gives you trouble.

Good luck!